# Sql query to calculate total cost using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

`Order details` table contains `catalog id` and its `quantity`.

`Catalog` has the price of the particular item.

For one order he or she can select only 2 items. The selected items total cost has to be generated and stored in orders table for a particular order using `order id`.

The columns in `my catalogs` are `id, name, price`.

The columns in `order details` are `id, order_id, catalog_id, quantity`.

The columns in `orders` table are `id, customer_id, total_cost`.

How can I calculate the total cost using 3 tables in mysql?

Comment: So this is about ordering catalogs? And no matter how many catalogs get ordered in one order, you want to select the total cost of two specific catalogs, e.g. catalog_ids 1 and 2 and store their total in the orders record? That sounds queer. And where are you stuck actually? You certainly know that you must multiply price and quantity for each of the two catalogs and then add up the results. Or does that already answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE orders
INNER JOIN (
SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity*price) total_price
FROM order_details
INNER JOIN my_catalogs
ON order_details.catalog_id = my_catalogs.id
GROUP BY order_id
) d
ON order.id = d.order_id
SET orders.total_cost = d.total_price;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```